# How to export multiple tables from a db into a workbook using laravel excel maatwebsite?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am introducing myself to the world of Laravel and a Maatwebsite Laravel Excel library, but I cannot find in its documentation to export multiple sheets or anywhere, how to export several different tables from a database in a single Excel workbook. Anyone who has suggestions or has achieved this with the Maatwebsite library?

This is my Export file:

````
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\tablasexcel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;


class tablasexcelexport implements 
 FromCollection 

{

     public function collection()
    {
        
        return collect(tablasexcel::getFinanciero());
    }  

    public function collection()
    {
        
        return collect(tablasexcel::getNegocios());
    }  
   
} ```

I am using Laravel 8 and Laravel Excel 3.1
````

Comment: Have you tried this multi-sheet export feature ? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/multiple-sheets.html

Comment: Hello, if I check it but it only does it with one table, I need it to do it with more than one table in the database and not filter by dates.